# django-modeltranslation - Django model get() SQL SELECT does not fetch translated fields

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, django-modeltranslation

I use django-modeltranslation to translate some model fields to Dutch (nl) and French (fr).

Now, all has been working fine except for one model:

```
@register(Association)
class AssociationTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = (
        'title',
        'name',
        'description',
    )
```

In the database, I can see the three fields with their translated equivalents: title, title_nl, title_fr, name, name_nl, name_fr, description, description_nl and description_fr. When I update these translated fields in django admin, or in the shell, they are saved correctly. **The problem occurs** when I fetch this data from the database. So if I fetch this data with `Association.objects.all()`, `Association.objects.get(id=1)`, or just look at it in the django admin detail view, I see for each translated field the default data. When I inspect the SQL query that Django executed, I see this strange query:

```
SELECT "member_association"."id",
       "member_association"."title",
       "member_association"."title",
       "member_association"."title",
       "member_association"."slug",
       "member_association"."name",
       "member_association"."name",
       "member_association"."name",
       "member_association"."description",
       "member_association"."description",
       "member_association"."description",
       "member_association"."mollie_api_key_test",
       "member_association"."mollie_api_key_live",
       "member_association"."mollie_profile_id",
       "member_association"."bank_account_number",
       "member_association"."created",
       "member_association"."last_modified"
  FROM "member_association"
 WHERE "member_association"."id" = '2'
```

As you can see, there is three times **title**, three times **name** and three times **description**, **without the language suffix**.

So for updating this model, django-modeltranslation works great but for fetching translated data from the database, it does not work for only one of my created models:

```
# WORKS
Association.objects.update(name_nl='naam', name_fr='nom')

# ALSO WORKS
association_obj.name_nl = 'naam'
association_obj.name_fr = 'nom'
association_obj.save()

# DOES NOT WORK
association_obj = Association.objects.get(id=1)
print(association_obj.name_nl) # prints 'naam' -> correct
print(association_obj.name_fr) # prints 'nom' -> incorrect
```

Can someone please help me with this error. I am already looking at this for days. I thought I would have made a typo somewhere but there is no typo to be found. I also tried deleting these fields, adding them again, syncing the database again with `./manage.py makemigrations`, `./manage.py migrate`, `./manage.py update_translation_fields` and `./manage.py sync_translation_fields` but still no success.

I am using python version 3.5.2, Django version 2.1.7 and django-modeltranslation version 0.14.4

Comment: I'm having similar problem, Python 3.7.3, Django 2.2.6 and modeltranslation 0.13.0. The issue seemed to appear out of nowhere in the last few days. I'll try to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: It seems the problem was related to a database query that was run too early in program initialization. In our case, we made some DB queries when creating a Django form class. I modified the queries to class __init__ method, and problem disappeared. It might be some kind of race condition, where DB queries are made before modeltranslation has finished bootstrapping everything.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it because it could be we also do some DB queries when creating a Django form class.